# TypeScript & React/JSX: tsc compiler error when supplying props to react component's superclass

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

Minimal example to reproduce:

```
const React = require("react");

class ExampleForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return <p>{ this.props.msg }</p>;
    }
};
```

Compiler command:

```
tsc --jsx react react_components/example.tsx
```

Error:

> react_components/example.tsx(5,9): error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

Is this a bug? Am I missing some `tsc` command-line flag/option?

EDIT:

installed types:

- "@types/react": "^15.0.25"
- "@types/node": "^7.0.23"

tsc version is 2.3.4

Comment: This might help. https://charleslbryant.gitbooks.io/hello-react-and-typescript/Samples/ComponentPropsAndState.html

Comment: @SLee This helps a lot. Can you rephrase as an answer so you get credit? Basically you have to add <x, y> after `React.Component`, with a good default value for `<x, y>` as `<any, any>`, and optionally specify interface for props.

Comment: glad to hear that it helps a lot. I think Nick's answer also covers the same. You can just give him the credit :) Upvote comment is enough for me

Comment: @BlackSheep, if you're using typescript although it's okay to use 'any', you should aim to add interfaces as soon as you know what they should look like. That way you get the benefits of using typescript. From the docs "The any type is a powerful way to work with existing JavaScript, allowing you to gradually opt-in and opt-out of type-checking during compilation.".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using an es6 import for React instead, and also make sure to delcare your interface for props.

e.g.

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface IProps {
  msg: string;
}

export class ExampleForm extends React.Component<IProps, {}> {
  constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return <p>{this.props.msg}</p>;
  }
}
```